# How does apps like TimeBro keeps track of how users spends time in different applications, gmail, word, outlook etc

Tags: time, timer

How can I create an application that starts a timer when a user begins typing an email in Gmail or Outlook after opening a word document? I would like to implement this feature using either C# or another programming language.

link to timebro: https://www.timebro.com/